# Design pattern for data bridge

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a design pattern which covers the following scenario when interfacing with an external system.

- Ecommerce orders placed in system A
- Order need to get to system B which stores the order in a set of database tables using different field names as System A
- Orders need to periodically get exported from system A to system B
- Order updates are fetched from system B and updated in system A periodically
- Data should be validated and errors/success events logged

Comment: I don't think there can be one design pattern that covers all the requirements that you talk about. It looks like you are looking for a high level design for an application. If that is the case, the question seems to be very broad.

Comment: It looks like you need an adapter between A and B